# Text Wrap For List And Dictionary In Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a program for finding out all possible combination of a set of numbers using Python Tkinter. But when the output send to the GUI. The output layouts are very messy (see picture).

[The output of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtcnK.jpg)

I used `wrap = 195` in `output_text.configure` but it didn't tidy up the output very well. Also, I tried to use `warp = "WORD"`and it sent out this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Eclipse IDE\Workspace\OCR A-LEVEL Programming Challenges\PIN Code Sequencer.py", line 15, in btn1_clicked
    output_text.configure(text = "Output: " + str(output1), wrap="WORD")
  File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1637, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1627, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "WORD"
```

I would like the program to show 2 - 3 combinations on a line.

Here are my codes:

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import *

window =Tk()
window.geometry("480x270")
window.title("PIN Code Combinations")

title1 = Label(window, text = "Input Numbers To Find Out All the Possible Combination!")
title1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

input1 = Entry(window, width = 20)
input1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

output_text = Label(window, text = "Output: ")
output_text.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

def btn1_clicked():
    temp = input1.get()
    output1 = list(permutations(temp))
    output_text.configure(text = "Output: " + str(output1), wrap=195)

btn1 = Button(window, text = "Calculate Combinations", command=btn1_clicked )
btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

Python Version 3.8

Comment: `wrap="WORD"` is not a valid value for that option.  Use `wrap="word"` (the actual value you want) or `wrap=WORD` (a Tkinter constant with that value).  But I don't think it's going to look any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use python's [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module to format the data for you. Or, you can write your own function to do the formatting. Tkinter itself doesn't have any support for formatting the data.

For example,

```
import pprint
...
text = pprint.pformat(output1, indent=4)
output_text.configure(text = "Output: " + text, wrap=195)
```